# Changing String input data into week / month format

Tags: string, date, excel, excel-2007, vba

I'm not sure if this is possible but I thought I would ask to see if any one may have a solution.

Issue:
I have a macro were the user inputs a date as a string (e.g. 021513) in an input box.  It is in string format as it's used to open a file (string at the end of the file name).

From this string (e.g. 021513) I need to derive the following in two separate fields:

- Week period (e.g. Week: 11th - 15th).
- Month (e.g. February).

Any help or thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Ciaran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do this with Excel formulas:

Assuming your string is cell A1, use the following formulas:

- B1 (date): `=DATE(right(A1,2)+2000,LEFT(A1,2),MID(A1,3,2))`
- C1 weekday: `=WEEKDAY(B1,2)` - this will return 1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday, etc.
- D1 Start of the week: `=B1-C1+1`
- E1 End of the week: `=D1+4`
- F1 Month: `=TEXT(B1,"MMMM")`

Comment: Peter (as always) & Ksenia - thank yyou both for your support and help.

Comment: @Peter Albert : Why not D1= B1-C1+1 , and E1=D1+7  ??

Comment: @qPCR4vir: good point! I changed it to D1 as this was a typo, but kept the +4, as I understood from the question that Mon-Fri was requested and not Mon-Mon...

Comment: @Peter Albert OK. And about the start of the week D1= B1-C1+1 ?(see the sings)

Comment: Mental note to self: Next time, your comment fully before answering it!

Answer (score 3):

You need `DateSerial` VBA function - it will return the actual Date value from the parts of your string using `Mid` and other text functions. Having actual date you'll be able to return e.g. month using `Month` function.

Perhaps string parts conversion to numbers using `CInt` will be required as well.